# Use <httpErrors> configuration in AspNetCore service

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.NET Core service which is hosted in IIS 10.0 with AspNetCoreModuleV2 (in process hosting). I need to display custom error pages in case of system errors and pass responses with unsuccessful code in case service returns it.

To summarize:
When user navigates to wrong url custom 404 error page should be displayed, when user requests unexisting resource with correct url 404 response should be passed from api with json body.
When user sends incorrect arguments for any action 400 response should be passed from api with json body. When IIS didn't manage to start application 500 error page should be displayed. Unfortunately I can't change api logic now.

I tried to configure custom error pages in Web.conifg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" existingResponse="PassThrough">
        <clear/>
        <!-- Remove default behaviour -->
        <remove statusCode="403"/>
        <remove statusCode="404"/>
        <remove statusCode="500"/>
        <!-- Return locally-stored error-page -->
        <error statusCode="403" path="error\403.html" responseMode="File"/>
        <error statusCode="404" path="error\404.html" responseMode="File"/>
        <error statusCode="500" path="error\500.html" responseMode="File"/>
      </httpErrors>
      <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
        <add initializationPage="/warmup" />
      </applicationInitialization>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I experimented with "existingResponse" setting modes:
When I set "Replace" mode all api requests greater or equal to 400 are replaced with error page regardless of error reason (api response or page not found).
When I set "PassThrough" or "Auto" mode all custom pages are ignored regardless of error reason.
I've read about "TrySkipIisCustomErrors" setting and "Auto" mode, but, as I understand, it works only for ASP.NET MVC projects.

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. here a link about how to add a custom error page you can use as a reference: [How to add a custom error page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/#how-to-add-a-custom-error-page).

Comment: My requirements are simple: display custom html page in case of system error (assembly absence in app folder -> custom html page with 500), display json from service in case service returns not success code (400 BadRequest). Don't know how to describe it more clearly. I didn't manage to achieve it by custom error pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to display custom html pages in case of system errors, such as

```
<error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="Custom-500.html" responseMode="File" />
```

but displaying the json content in case the service returns an unsuccessful code cannot be done.